# Linear Maps and Inverses

Tags: linear-algebra

- $S$ and $T$ are linear transformations of $\mathbb{R^3}$ which have inverses. Show that $ST$ has and inverse and that $(ST)^{-1}=T^{-1}S^{-1}$.

Let $ST(X)=X$ for any $X \in \mathbb{R^n}$. Since $S, T$ are linear and these have inverses, then we have $T^{-1}S^{-1}$ is linear an exist so

$$T^{-1}S^{-1} S T (X)= X = T^{-1}S^{-1} (X)$$,

hence $T^{-1}S^{-1}$ is an inverse of $ST$.

**Can you check my answer?**

Comment: Can you check my answer?

Answer (score 1):

You've rather overcomplicated the issue: you know that $T^{-1}S^{-1}$ is a linear map that exists (since $S$ and $T$ have inverses), so all you need to is check that it's an inverse for ST. As a hint: this result is true in all kinds of more general spaces (all the way up to an arbitrary associative algebra), so there's no need to be messing around with evaluating your functions.

Also, $S(X)T(Y)$ is *not* equal to $ST(XY)$, and $T(X) = 0$ implying $X = 0$ is *not* sufficient for $T$ to be invertible (it also needs to be surjective).

Comment: may you check my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Let $ST(X)=X$ for any $X \in \mathbb{R^n}$. Since $S, T$ are linear and these have inverses, then we have $T^{-1}S^{-1}$ is linear an exist so

$$T^{-1}S^{-1} S T (X)= X = T^{-1}S^{-1} (X)$$,

hence $T^{-1}S^{-1}$ is an inverse of $ST$.

**Can you check my answer?**

Comment: I'd like some more detail. Thus far, you've basically just written down "it is because I say so". Something like $(T^{-1}S^{-1})(ST) = T^{-1}(S^{-1}S)T = T^{-1}1T = T^{-1}T = 1$, and $(ST)(T^{-1}S^{-1}) = S(TT^{-1})S^{-1} = S1S^{-1} = SS^{-1} = 1$, so $T^{-1}S^{-1}$ is the inverse of $ST$.